# Get the greatest ID

Tags: jquery

PLease anyone give me a solution for this.
The problem is 
I am generating thd ids dynamically in an html page with jquery.
I want to find the greatest Id if the ids are for eg:
id0,id1,id2..........
PLease anyone give me a solution.
Thankyou for reading.

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: It's fastest to save the max id in a variable on create time.

Comment: As Joel states, if you are generating the IDs, then you already should know the highest one...no need to go find it.

Answer (score 5):

working example of following code can be found at http://www.jsfiddle.net/LdgN9/2/

```
// create an array
var ar = new Array();
// for each element with id that starts with 'id'
$('[id^="id"]').each(
     function(){
                // add it to the array (only its numeric part)
                ar.push(
                        // extract the numeric part to be added in the array
                        parseInt( $(this).attr('id').replace('id','') )
                      );
               });
// find the max value in the array 
alert('id' + Math.max.apply( Math, ar ));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're *not* adding the elements to the page so that they're in DOM order naturally, then you can find it like this:

```
function withMaxId() {
  var max = -1, maxe = null;
  $('[id^=id').each(function() {
    var idv = parseInt(this.id.replace(/^id/, ''), 10);
    if (idv > max) {
      max = idv;
      maxe = this;
    }
  });
  return maxe; // change to just "max" if you only want the id value
}
```

Of course if you know more about the elements you could replace `$('*')` with something more selective.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could replace it with `[id^='id']` :)

Comment: Well sure; in fact I probably should change it to make sure that there's an "id" value in the elements :-)

Comment: `[id]` in the selector will speed it up in the smarter browser engines as well :) `[id^='id']` is doing the same thing as you are currently with the regex though, just using `.indexOf() == 0` though, http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L685

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
alert($('element[id^="id"]:last').attr('id'));
```

**Note:** Since you have not specified, I assume that order of elements is ascending in the DOM.

Comment: That's assuming that the elements are placed in the DOM according to their numerical order. What if `id5` is before `id1`?

Comment: @J-P: That's right but i assume that order is in numerical in the DOM of course.